# Some parts of image vibrate in moblie landscape mode

Tags: html, css, image

this is the website link [shakir photography](http://shakirfotography.com/)

When you view it in mobile landscape mode , some parts of image gets vibrate or pixelate or dont know how to describe it. For Example : i saw in 360x640 . Take a look on it.

Note:if you are viewing in real mobile device , after changing to landscape mode , refresh the page to get full size photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the resolution and size and loaded in m. subdomain .. now problem solved.